# forecast product demand in one week using machine learning approach

Tags: machine-learning, forecast, forecasting

I'm trying to predict product demand in store. The predictors I have include price,  competitor's price, store ID, date.  My target variable is sales volume (in a particular store). What I need to predict is sales in a store one week in advance.

I'm thinking about how I should approach this problem. The goal is to predict sales one week in advance,  I'm a little confused about how I should use predictors for prediction. How I should do the model validation (for predictions one week in advance). How can I incorporate seasonality in the model if I use random forest...

Really appreciate it if anyone can help clarifying this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Do you have historical weekly data for sales and predictors ?